# WCF Message Security with Certification without primary key

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, certificate

I'm trying to connect to SOAP web service (JAVA) with WCF. The request must contain Timestamp and BinarySecurityToken. The problem is that a certificate I received does not contain a Private Key (and there is no way to get it) and the request fails with an error "The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate."

I tried with self-signed certificate that I created and the request message looks like it should (of course authentication fails).

```
<basicHttpBinding >             
 <binding name="VerificacionJugadoresBinding">
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
  </security>
 </binding>
</basicHttpBinding >

myClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"myCert.cer");
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without a private key? Any other options instead of WCF? It must be in .NET though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Message security with a certificate client needn’t a private key of the service certificate. Only we need to do is established the trust relationship between the server and the client, namely we should install the service certificate of the server in the RootCA on the client-side, and the server is supposed to install the client certificate in the server-side RootCA.
Please refer to the below document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. The problem still exists though...

The error is the same: missing primary key

I did install the servers certificate on client machine (root ca). And I'm using TransportWithMessageCredential security mode (since there is a https connection)

Exceptions is thrown at: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.GetSignatureFormatter(String algorithm)
   at System.IdentityModel.SignedXml.ComputeSignature(SecurityKey signingKey)

Comment: Have you established the trust relationship between the server-side and the client-side? Besides, we ought to ensure that the application has access permission to the certificate.  Please add the Everyone account to the certificate accordingly.

Comment: I believe I did. If I try with a self signed certificate (which contain a private key) the correct message is sent successfully - but then rejected by the server since the public key (<BinarySecurityToken> element) is invalid. Should I specify the certificate for HTTPS protocol manually?

Comment: Also if I use   <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/> the message is send correctly, so I believe that the transport is not the issue here.

Comment: Is your server and client the same machine? How do you ensure that the server trusts the certificate provided by the client?

Comment: No, the server is not on the same machine (3rd party api).

It's a SSL connection so the servers certificate is in trusted CAs store.

Another certificate was provided by the 3rd party which should be used to generate BinarySecurityToken and apparently  sign the body part of the message.

Am I missing something?